# Bug in parallel computing

Tags: parallelization

The following is a simplified example. We construct a library function f and another library function g, in which the library function f is called.

```
f = Compile[x, Integrate[1 + t^2, {t, 0, x}], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
g = With[{f = f}, Compile[x, x + f[x], CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
```

CompilePrint shows the following for the function g:

1   R1 = LibraryFunction[<>, compiledFunction0, {{Real, 0, Constant}}, Real][ R0]]
2   R2 = R0 + R1
3   Return

Now we test the functions f and g on the main kernel and on two subkernels:

```
LaunchKernels[];
DistributeDefinitions[f,g];
f[2.3]
g[1.2]
ParallelEvaluate[f[2.3], 1]
ParallelEvaluate[g[1.2], 1]
ParallelEvaluate[g[1.2], 2]

(* Out[7]= 6.35567  
  Out[8]= 2.976  
  Out[9]= 6.35567  
  Out[10]= 2.976  
  During evaluation of In[5]:= LinkObject::linkd: Unable to communicate with closed link LinkObject["C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\MathKernel" -subkernel -noinit -mathlink -noicon,225,5]. >>  
  During evaluation of In[5]:= KernelObject::rdead: Subkernel connected through KernelObject[2,local] appears dead. >>  
  Out[11]= $Failed  *)
```

The evaluations on the main kernel and on subkernel 1 are fast. On subkernel 1 we first evaluated f and next g. On subkernel 2 we immediately called g, without having used f before. The subkernel crashes. I am running Mathematica 10.0.2 32 bits on Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried `CompilePrint[f]`? The presence of `Integrate` means it just calls `MainEvaluate`. Your simplified example may well need changing...

Comment: @blochwave. Indeed this function f calls MainEvaluate. In my real situation there is no call to MainEvaluate and nevertheless the subkernel crashes. When I played a little bit with the simplified example, I found an even more amazing behaviour: when you first evaluate f and then call g on a subkernel, there is no problem; when you call g before having called f the subkernel crashes.  I adapted my question accordingly.

Comment: Rather than using `With`, can you try `CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}` for your function `g`?

Comment: @blochwave. In this example, yes. The result is then a function g that does not call anything else, and that works fine. In my real situation f is a library function obtained with LibraryFunctionLoad, and with such a function this workaround does not work. The bug that I report here is the fact that a subkernel crashes in a situation that it should not crash. I did not yet test if in my real situtation the crash does not happen when I first evaluate all functions that will be called on all subkernels. Anyway, I think that this should be superfluous.

Comment: I have the same thing going on - Mathematica 10.4, Windows 10.
Whenever I call Parallel table with any lengthy amount of time it crashes and gives these same types of warnings.

Answer (score 8):

As demonstrated by the asker, Mathematica is failing to distribute the definitions of C-compiled library functions in a way that can be called by other C-compiled functions.

**I agree this is a bug.** I have submitted a bug report to Wolfram Research and hope to update the post to include the result of that.

**1.** One workaround is to compile to C only in the last function. You can use

> CompilationOptions->{"InlineCompiledFunctions"->True}

to ensure it all goes to optimized C-code. 
(if you remove the CompilationTarget->"C" it compiles to the Wolfram Virtual Machine.)

**2.** Another option is to first call all of the 
child functions from the parallel Kernels, which appear to get loaded properly for use. For your example

```
LaunchKernels[];
f = Compile[x, Integrate[1 + t^2, {t, 0, x}], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
g = With[{f = f}, Compile[x, x + f[x], CompilationTarget -> "C"]];
ParallelEvaluate[f];
ParallelEvaluate[g[1.2], 2]
```

> {2.976, 2.976}

Although a question wasn't asked, I hope one this solves the askers problems, as it solved mine.

*Update 7/21/2016:* I received an email containing the following.

> I was able to reproduce the issue, and consequently, I filed a report
>   with our development team raising the issues and also shared your
>   contact information with them so you can be notified once the issue is
>   resolved.

*Update 8/26/2016:* The situation appears the same in version 11.0.0.0.

Comment: +1.  Note `ParallelEvaluate[f]` is sufficient in your second option (evaluate only `f` instead of `f[2,3]`).

Comment: Nice - I edited accordingly.

Comment: See also comments here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43070/12

Comment: "Mathematica is failing to distribute the definitions of C-compiled library functions" <- I am not sure if this can be called a bug, although it is definitely not user-friendly.  A LibraryFunction is essentially a reference to an external resource.  To make it work properly, it should be created/loaded separately on each subkernel.  There are many such examples where something created on one kernel can't be used on another.  Think opening a file.  You can an `InputStream` expression. It won't work on another kernel unless you open the file there too.

Comment: Or think loading a package.  You need to use ParallelNeeds and can't just distribute.  Or think using managed library expressions.  Do ``<< TriangleLink` ``, then `TriangleCreate[]`.  You'll get a `TriangleExpression`.  It can be distributed as an *expression*, but on subkernels it simply loses its meaning (which is a reference to some C-side data structure present only in main kernel memory).  There will naturally always be such cases, and it is unreasonable to call them bugs.  Perhaps compiled functions are a bit special because they are so common.  But the reasonable thing is still to ...

Comment: ... compile (or load) them separately on each subkernel.  After all it's just a fancy LibraryLink library (which I assume you would try to load explicitly) which has a special byte-code fallback.

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs, I think this is an important point to discuss. According to the documentation DistributeDefinitions "distributes all definitions for the symbols to all parallel kernels." While I don't expect this to work for packages (or files), I expect it to work for functions. Anyway, if a separate distribution system (like Needs) is needed here then AFAIK they have yet to write one. The only distribution workaround is to force implicit distribution by calling the C-compiled library function from the WVM.

Comment: Also note that manual distribution is not needed if library function is not C-compiled, but rather WVM-compiled (even though it appears as a library function call in the C-code).